# What is the magnetic quantum number for $p_x$, $p_y$, $p_z$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

After tons of research, I've come to the conclusion that the $p_x$ and $p_y$ orbitals can have either $m_\ell=+1$ or $-1$, but $p_z$ is $0$.

But my professor said that we can attribute any $m_\ell$ value from $- 1,0,+1$ to $p_x.p_y$ and $p_z$.

So who's wrong?

Comment: What exactly makes you believe your conclusion?

Comment: I mean because tons of pages said the same thing

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33645/

Comment: oh shoot, so my professor is wrong :|

Comment: In your standard orientation of axis {xyz} its true m=0 for $p_z$ orbital. But how you assign the axis is arbitrary: {xyz} ,{yzx} ,{zxy}, i.e. how the polar angles are defined wrt cartesian axis is arbitrary, provided it preserves orientation. So overall, the same $p_z$ orbital can take all values of m. We are dealing with spherically symmetric system, all directions are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

The $\text{p}_x$, $\text{p}_y$, $\text{p}_z$ orbitals are "real" $\ell=1$ wavefunctions.
The actual angular wavefunctions (i.e., simultaneous eigenfunctions of $\hat{{L}}^2$ and $\hat{L}_z$) are the spherical harmonics:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Y}_{1+} &= -\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}} \sin\theta \hspace{0.1em} e^{i\phi}
= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( \text{p}_x(\theta,\phi) + i\text{p}_y(\theta,\phi) \big)
\,,\\
\mathrm{Y}_{1-} &= \phantom{-}\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}} \sin\theta \hspace{0.1em} e^{i\phi}
= \phantom{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( \text{p}_x(\theta,\phi) - i\text{p}_y(\theta,\phi) \big)
\,,\\
\mathrm{Y}_{0} &= \phantom{-}\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi}} \cos\theta \quad\,
= \text{p}_z(\theta,\phi)
\,.
\end{align}
These are complex-valued functions, so some people (especially chemists) prefer to visualize them by splitting their real and imaginary parts, and that is the "real" orbitals $\text{p}_x$, $\text{p}_y$, $\text{p}_z$.
This messes up the diagonalization:
\begin{align}
\text{p}_x(\theta,\phi) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( {-\mathrm{Y}_{1+}(\theta,\phi)} + \mathrm{Y}_{1-}(\theta,\phi) \big)
\,,\\
\text{p}_y(\theta,\phi) &= \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \big( {\mathrm{Y}_{1+}(\theta,\phi)} + \mathrm{Y}_{1-}(\theta,\phi) \big)
\,,\\
\text{p}_z(\theta,\phi) &= \mathrm{Y}_{10}(\theta,\phi)
\,.
\end{align}
From this expression, it is clear that $\text{p}_x$ and $\text{p}_y$ orbitals are $\frac{1}{2}:\frac{1}{2}$ superpositions of $m=+1$ and $m=-1$, and $\text{p}_z$ orbital is the $m=0$ eigenstate.
$\text{p}_x$ and $\text{p}_y$ are orthogonal, as they mixes $m=+1$ and $m=-1$ with different relative phase factors.
(Just to be clear—of course, we are speaking about $\ell=1$ states.)

To reiterate, $\text{p}_x$ and $\text{p}_y$ are not eigenstates of $\hat{L}_z$. It is kind of "grammatically wrong" to say that "$\text{p}_x$ has $m=+1$" for instance. $\text{p}_x$ is not an eigenstate of $\hat{L}_z$ and the eigenvalue $m$ is not defined at all. The best we can say is that $\text{p}_x$ is a superposition of $m=+1$ and $m=-1$ eigenstates.

Comment: so if i understood you correctly, ml of Pz=0 but ml of Px=+or - 1 and ml of Py= +or-1? If so, can't it be ml of Pz=+or-1 and Px=+or-1 and Py=0 like the comment of KP99 that says that we can give any value fir Px, Py, Pz as long as the orientation is preserved?

Comment: Dear Elie Makdissi, oh, that's also an insightful viewpoint. Yes. 1) px and py do not have a definite L_z eigenvalue, yet they are superpositions of L_z = +1 and -1. 2) The functional form of px becomes the same as pz (i.e., ~cos theta) if we rotate the coordinate system as (x,y,z)→(y,z,x). Therefore, you can say that p_x is an m=+1 eigenstate of L_x. 3) This can be also seen by checking out the components of the rotation matrix in the \ell=1 spherical basis representation of SO(3).

Comment: The reason why I avoided saying that in my explanations is that it does not generalizes for higher-\ell orbitals, d, f, g, and so on: the "real orbitals" are not in general mere rotations of the L_z- eigenfunctions. For example, take a "real orbital" d_{x^2-y^2}. Redefining axes as (x,y,z)→(y,z,x) does not make it to d_{z^2} (m=0) neither a complex-valued spherical harmonics with m≠0. But, it is still a linear combination of spherical harmonics in the transformed basis. Recall: for \ell=1 all orbitals have the same shape, but this does not hold for higher \ell.

Comment: aha thankss a lott <3!